# Swift - How to set custom view by text length

Tags: ios, layout, uiview, uilabel, swift4

Here is my code,

```
func bannerNotification(text: String){
    let container = UIView()
    let image = UIImageView()
    let label = UILabel()
    container.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 100)
    container.backgroundColor = .blue
    image.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 50, width: 30, height: 30)
    image.image = UIImage(named: "passport")
    label.frame = CGRect(x: image.bounds.maxX + 35, y: 50, width: container.frame.size.width - 100, height: 50)
    label.backgroundColor = .red
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.font = UIFont(name:"Helvetica Neue", size: 15)
    label.text = text
    container.addSubview(image)
    container.addSubview(label)
    self.view.addSubview(container)
}
```

According to this code the container and Image is coming on right position but if I pass small text so my text is not inline with Image, means **my image top position and text top position should be same**.

If I will pass a big text so **container bottom and Label bottom should be same** and all text should be there not truncated and **Image and Label should be inline from the top**.

[image: Expected Behavior]

[image: Real Behavior]

Comment: First, it will help if you show a few images... how it looks now with short text and with long text, and how you ***want it to look*** with short text and with long text. Second, why aren't you using auto-layout constraints?

Comment: Added a pictures please check and I don't know how to add layouts programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really want to use auto-layout for this, particularly since you're using multi-line label -- meaning, it will vary in height.

Here's an example - read through the comments to understand the auto-layout constraints:

```
class KingViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        bannerNotification(text: "Banner Test")
        //bannerNotification(text: "Banner Test with lots of text to wrap onto multiple lines. Of the many advantages with using auto-layout, notice that the banner will stretch when you rotate the device.")
    }

    func bannerNotification(text: String){
        let container = UIView()
        let image = UIImageView()
        let label = UILabel()
        container.addSubview(image)
        container.addSubview(label)
        self.view.addSubview(container)
        
        [image, label, container].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }

        container.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.5, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        //image.image = UIImage(named: "passport")
        image.image = UIImage(named: "swiftRed")
        label.backgroundColor = .yellow
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.font = UIFont(name:"Helvetica Neue", size: 15)
        label.text = text

        // respect the safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain container Top / Leading / Trailing
            container.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            container.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            container.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            
            // we'll use the label height to determine the container height
            
            // image view Top = 8 / Leading = 15
            image.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            image.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 15.0),
            
            // image view width = 30 / height == width (1:1 ratio)
            image.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30.0),
            image.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: image.widthAnchor),
            
            // label Top aligned to Top of image view
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: image.topAnchor),
            
            // label Leading == image view Trailing + 20
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: image.trailingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            
            // label Trailing = container Trailing - 15
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -15.0),

            // container bottom should be
            //  At Least 8-pts below the image view bottom
            // AND
            //  At Least 8-pts below the label bottom
            container.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: image.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            container.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: label.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),

        ])
        
    }

}
```

Result, with short text:

[image]

Result with long text:

[image]

Note that it auto-adjusts when the size changes - such as with device rotation:

[image]