# iOS - How to create custom animated banner without third party framework in Swift

Tags: swift, animation, uiview, autolayout

I need to create a custom drop down banner which will drop from the top and then will go up in few seconds.
for custom banner UIView I am referring this question and this is perfect example and thats what I want, because my banner is also dynamic and this will adjust height on the base of text.

[Swift - How to set custom view by text length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63496141/swift-how-to-set-custom-view-by-text-length)

but not sure how to make this animated. I have write a code for animation and its working perfectly but not sure how this animation will work with the custom view that I mentioned above.

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    bannerView()
}

func bannerView() {
    let container = UIView()
    container.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    container.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -200, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 200)
    UIApplication.shared.windows[0].addSubview(container)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
            container.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 200)
            
        }) { (finished) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4,delay: 2.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
                container.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: -200, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 200)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: yeah I tried it but doesn't work. :(

Comment: do you have any idea how this will work together? Custom banner with navigation? @DonMag

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're doing. You mention *"navigation"* ... Are you trying to show a view that slides down and covers the navigation bar when using a `UINavigationController`?

Comment: my apologies,I was trying to write custom banner with animation, and yes right.. this view will slides down from the top of screen which has UINavigationBar. so basically this will be a success or failure notification banner for user but dynamic. @DonMag

Comment: any help? @DonMag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a fan of adding subviews to windows instead to the view hierarchy... but, if that's really what you want to do, give this a try (review the comments in the code).

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    bannerNotification(text: "Banner Test with lots of text to wrap onto multiple lines. We're using explict frames and calculating the height of the (potentially multiline) label.")
}

func bannerNotification(text: String){

    // create a "container" view
    let container = UIView()
    
    // create a label
    let label = UILabel()
    
    // add label to container
    container.addSubview(label)
    
    // color / font / text properties as desired
    container.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.5, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    label.backgroundColor = .yellow
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.font = UIFont(name:"Helvetica Neue", size: 16.0)
    label.text = text
    
    // padding on left/right of label
    let hPadding: CGFloat = 16.0
    
    // padding on top of label - account for status bar?
    let vTopPadding: CGFloat = 32.0
    
    // padding on bottom of label
    let vBotPadding: CGFloat = 16.0

    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    
    // get reference to window 0
    let w = UIApplication.shared.windows[0]
    
    // add container to window
    w.addSubview(container)
    
    // calculate label height
    let labelSize = label.systemLayoutSizeFitting(CGSize(width: width - (hPadding * 2.0),
                                                  height: UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize.height))
    
    // rect for container view - start with .zero
    var containerRect = CGRect.zero
    // set its size to screen width x calculated label height + top/bottom padding
    containerRect.size = CGSize(width: width, height: labelSize.height + vTopPadding + vBotPadding)
    // set container view's frame
    container.frame = containerRect
    
    // rect for label - container rect inset by padding values
    let labelRect = containerRect.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: vTopPadding, left: hPadding, bottom: vBotPadding, right: hPadding))
    // set the label's frame
    label.frame = labelRect

    // position container view off-the-top of the screen
    container.frame.origin.y = -container.frame.size.height
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
            container.frame.origin.y = 0
        }) { (finished) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4,delay: 2.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
                container.frame.origin.y = -container.frame.size.height
            })
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
   var stringText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,"
    bannerNotification(text: stringText)
}


func bannerNotification(text: String) {
    let container = UIView()
    let image = UIImageView()
    let label = UILabel()
    container.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:-100, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 100)
    container.backgroundColor = .blue
    image.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 60, width: 30, height: 30)
    image.image = UIImage(named: "passport")
    label.frame = CGRect(x: image.bounds.maxX + 35, y: 40, width: container.frame.size.width - 100, height: 50)
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.font = UIFont(name:"Helvetica Neue", size: 15)
    label.text = text
    container.addSubview(image)
    container.addSubview(label)
    UIApplication.shared.windows[0].addSubview(container)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
            container.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 100)
            
        }) { (finished) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4,delay: 2.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
                container.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: -100, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 100)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Try this I hope that will work for you.

Comment: @DonMag what do you think this will help ?

Comment: yeah this is working but not for long text. @DonMag